# How to use tkvw/admin-on-rest in my project

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am trying to use tkvw/admin-on-rest(https://github.com/tkvw/admin-on-rest/tree/next-tkvw) in my project.

In the 'admin on rest' documentation it is mentioned to do the following steps to use a modified version of admin on rest.
I Checkedout the project(tkvw is the modified repository of AOR) from git. From the checked out directory I am executing

cd admin-on-rest
npm link

and in my personal project(where I am using tkvw/admin-on-rest) I am executing
cd ../my-project
npm link react-admin ( The name in package.json is react-admin in the next-tkvw branch)

I am getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-admin' in my project where I am referencing 'react-admin'

How to use tkvw(next-tkvw) branch in my project ?

Comment: I revised the details

Comment: Are you trying to use Admin-On-Rest as an external dependency in your existing project?

Comment: yes, I have a project in which I am using admin-on-rest